# cat ./* >> large.txt decreases in size

Tags: bash, cat

I'm a novice in bash scripting. I wrote a script that concatenates many files from different directories into large files

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for f in foo/$1/*; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        for d in $f/*; do
                if [ -d "$d" ]; then
                file=$( echo ${d##*/} )
                mkdir -p bar/$1/"$file"/fastq/
                cat $d/*/fastq_pass/* >> bar/$1/"$file"/fastq/$file.fastq.gz
                        fi
                done
    fi
done
```

I've noticed that some of merged files lost 1-2 GB in size, which is weird because other files are ok. When I tried to do

```bsh
cat foo/* >> bar/largefile.fastq.gz
```

there was no loss. So it's definitely because of my script. Where's error?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you cannot create a new valid `.gz` file by concatenating several smaller files together.

Comment: @doneal24, why not? i've concatenated small gz files to a large gz several times manually with cat

Comment: @doneal24 Yes you can. It's a feature of the gzip format (and of the bzip2 and xz formats too, actually).

Comment: How do you measure the file sizes and how do you determine that the files shrink?

Comment: @Kusalananda, after running the script, I measured the size using du -sc of multiple files in the source directory and the large file in the destination directory. Then, I manually run cat, after which repeated with du -sc. I noticed that the file after script is less in size than after manual cat

Comment: Then your script probably does not do the same `cat` operations as you did manually.

Answer (score -1):

For efficiency, filesystems allocate disk space in clusters of blocks. Thus, a "1 byte" file would be allocated a whole cluster. Concatenating 100 "1 byte" files, producing 100 bytes of data would still take a single cluster.

Cluster and block sizes can vary, there's a subfield of Performance Analysis dedicated to optimizing for a particular application.

Comment: so how to edit my code so that cat would concatenate files without loss? because when I run cat independently for one direction, it works fine